# How to render Jbuidler partials inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I am trying to render a jbuilder partial in a model like this:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def fcm_format
    Jbuilder.new do |json|
      json.partial! 'api/v1/gigs/summary', gig: remindable
    end
  end
end
```

But this gives me the following error.

> TypeError: {:gig=>#} is not a symbol nor a string

Is there a way to render a partial inside of a model or a decorator maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Jbuilder` instance does not respond to `partial!`. `partial!` is contained in `JbuilderTemplate`. `JbuilderTemplate`'s constructor is looking for a context before calling super on `Jbuilder.new`.

So the solution is to add a context. The problem is that within `JbuilderTemplate`, the context calls the method `render` and in models we don't have a built in way to render. So we need to stub out our context with an `ActionController::Base` object.

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Returns a builder
  def fcm_format
    context = ActionController::Base.new.view_context
    JbuilderTemplate.new(context) do |json|
      json.partial! 'api/v1/gigs/summary', gig: remindable
    end
  end

  # Calls builder.target! to render the json
  def as_json
    fcm_format.target!
  end

  # Calls builder.attributes to return a hash representation of the json
  def as_hash
    fcm_format.attributes!
  end
end
```

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one upvote.